# Why HTML Element X Position Value Doubled (x2) When updating its X Position Value After Drag Release Event from Angular CDK drag-drop?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, drag-and-drop

I have an HTML element that has the following roles:

1. Move automatically at the positive x-level every time an Obsarbalve emits a new value.
2. Move manually at the positive and negative x-level by dragging and dropping it.

The second role is implemented using Angular drag and drop CDK. and the problem occurs when the drag action is released **(cdkDragReleased)**

The following function called when the drag is realeased:

```
onDragEnd(e: CdkDragRelease){
    let newosistion =  e.source.element.nativeElement.getClientRects().item(0).left;

    this.facade.setBehaviorSubject(newposistion);
  }
```

setBehaviorSubject will update the Observable next value, resulting in updating the value of the element based on role number one mentioned above.

The final result is to have a doubled position x value. (value from the dragging + value from the observable)

I need to get the actual value where the user release the element. How can I prevent this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

I've found the reason!

Since Angular drag and drop CDK apply a property transform: translate3d(x,y,z) in order to move the element, I had to  reset the transform property In the method that takes CdkDragEnd   with

```
  onDragEnd(e: CdkDragEnd) {
    e.source._dragRef.reset();
  }
```